# Who is the god on the Immortals poster?

Tags: greek-myth, immortals, poster-design

In *Immortals*, one of the gods has this amazing helmet:
[image: Movie poster showing helmet]

During the film, they never refer to him by name.  Which god is this?

Comment: Haven't seen the movie myself, but the helm looks like one that might be worn by the likes of Helios or Apollo.  That picture does bear some semblance to Corey Sevier who is credited with the latter role on IMDB.

Comment: @Iszi Actually, a different god was wearing a helmet that had these flame-like wire frame designs.  It made his head look like the sun from some angles.  I bet he was Helios or Apollo.

Comment: In Greek mythology, Apollo has sun rays coming out of his head. Helios, on the other hand, is the personification of the sun. Helios is a Titan and Apollo is an Olympian. That is the difference between them.

Comment: If you want to buy his ridiculous hat, it's on http://www.golive.com.au/action/action-films-2010s/immortals/immortals-aries-daniel-sharman-helmet-movie-props

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is Aries, played by Daniel Sharman.

Comment: Shouldn't that be "Ares" (as in God of War)  instead of "Aries" (which I think is a star sign, and yes, I know this is a very old answer).